# How could I use FullCalendar Module in angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am using FullCalendar from angular primeng but it is giving me an error:

> "Cannot find module '@fullcalendar/angular' or its corresponding type
> declarations" after import it into app-module.

I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

I want to use FullCalender in my angular project. I have run a
command :

```
npm install @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/list @fullcalendar/timegrid @fullcalendar/interaction.
```

and after that I am trying to import it in app-module but is giving an error. Is there anything that I have missed in my code. I am referring https://primeng.org/fullcalendar for demo and going step by step.

I have got some solutions on Internet but not working -
I have tried command: `npm install fullcalendar@4.0.0-alpha.2 --save`

I think something else is there that I don't know. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually quite helpful this time - you really are missing the `@fullcalendar/angular` package.

Run this in the command line:

```
 npm install @fullcalendar/core @fullcalendar/list @fullcalendar/timegrid @fullcalendar/interaction @fullcalendar/angular
```

I simply added `@fullcalendar/angular` at the end.